# Would there be a flame front in an air-fuel mixture?

Tags: pressure, temperature, combustion

Suppose a piston enclosing an amount of air-fuel mixture and then this piston compresses the mixture to the point of auto ignition, if every part of the mixture ignite simultaneously is it safe to say that there isn't a flame front because it can't move because there is no longer a combustible mixture?

If there is a flame front are they multiple flame fronts?

Also if my reasoning is correct does that type of combustion have a name?

Comment: I believe your essential chemical physics question is: If an ideal stoichiometric oxidizer-fuel mixture such as [Oxyhydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyhydrogen) is compressed or heated, will the mixture auto-ignite everywhere before a flame-front can propagate from the first auto-ignition point? It may be possible to estimate the answer from [chemical collision theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_theory#Rate_equations) and [thermal flame theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminar_flame_speed), and will depend on the compression rate, volume, density and other factors.

Comment: Would a flame front exist by definition in this case because a flame front would require some unburnt mixture to propagate further but since the whole mixture ignites simultaneously there wouldn't be any mixture remaining for the flame to move that was my reasoning and I wanted to know if it was true . Besides if there is a flame front where would it originate from in this case

Comment: I disagree with the closure, since this is essentially a physical chemistry or chemical physics question about the fundamentals of auto-ignition, not an engineering question about diesel engines or knocking or octane.  It may be, however, that you might get better answers on Chemistry Stack Exchange than on Physics SE.

Answer (score 0):

In a gasoline engine the ideal combustion is a flame front initiated by the spark plug.  When detonation (knock, ping, etc) occurs it is more like an explosion and the shock wave can damage components.  This does not happen in a diesel engine because the fuel is burned as it is introduced into the superheated air, more like a stationary flame front.